# VueJS - jest: How to test/spy the methods which are getting called inside the watcher?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

Sample Code from the VueJs components. Note that I'm trying to cover the watcher as well as the method

```
computed: {
              ...mapGetters({
               resourceLinks: `tools/${storeGetters.resourceLinks}`,
            }),
        },
        methods: {
              formatData(data) {
                this.setSocialLinks();
            },
        },
    },
        watch: {
            resourceLinks(data) {
                this.formatData(data);
            },
        },
```

Comment: Oh come on man! The docs are great, spend 5 minutes to read them. You will learn much much more then just this: https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/wrapper/#setmethods

Answer (score 2):

expect(wrapper.vm.$options.watch.resourceLinks.call(wrapper.vm, resourceLinks1));